# Locality Preserving Hash Function

Tags: java, hash-function

Is there any Java library that provides an implementation (or several) of a [Locality Preserving Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_preserving_hashing) for Strings?

Comment: For what Java type? E.g. `Integer.hashCode()` already has this property. How do you define distance between Strings or arbitrary Java objects?

Comment: @tomasz distance betweens string can be obtained by converting their characters to ascii

Comment: At least I know two possible distances - Levenshtein distance and lexicographical distance.

Comment: I didn't specify but I am looking for a locality preserving hash function for Strings

Answer (score -2):

You probably can use HashcodeBuilder from Jakarta: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

I hope this is what you mean.

Comment: this is exactly what he doesent need

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is not what I am looking for.